# How to add QLayout to QTablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I learned to create QTablewidge and tried to add QLayout to the widget. However, I do not think it is working. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
def main(): 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = QWidget()
    table = QTableWidget()
    # initiate table
    table.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget Example @pythonspot.com")
    table.resize(400, 400)
    gui.setGeometry(400,400,400,400)
    table.setRowCount(7)
    table.setColumnCount(2)
    table.setColumnWidth(0, 80)
    table.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
    # rowPosition = table.rowCount()
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['skew','duty_cycle_mean'])
    # set data
    table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Item (1,1)"))
    table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem('Item (1,2)'))
    table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Item (2,1)"))
    table.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Item (2,2)"))
    table.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Item (3,1)"))
    table.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Item (3,2)"))
    table.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Item (4,1)"))
    table.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Item (4,2)"))
    table.setItem(4, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Item (5,1)"))
    table.setItem(4, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Item (5,2)"))
    table.setItem(5, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Item (6,1)"))
    table.setItem(5, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Item (6,2)"))
    table.setItem(6, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Item (7,1)"))
    table.setItem(6, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Item (7,2)"))
    vertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    horizontal = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    vertical.addLayout(horizontal)
    vertical.addWidget(table)
    gui.setLayout(vertical)
    gui.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

what is wrong with the code? I just want the QTableWidget expands horizontally and vertically when I drag the QTableWidget. It troubles me a lot and I still have a lot of other problems.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The rows and columns of a table do not automatically resize when the table is resized.

Comment: So do we need to add other layouts to the table widget? Thank you very much.